# How can I find the ad library used by an android application

Tags: android, static-analysis, android-library, android-lint, advertisement-server

I have downloaded the source codes of open source android apps. I have around 2000 of them. I wish to do an analysis on ad libraries used by android apps. I have 2 questions,

1. How can I find whether an app uses ad library
2. If it uses, how can I find the name of the ad library (eg. AdMob, InMobi etc.)

Comment: -follow this link-https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download

Comment: I have been reading about admob by google from this link (and some other pages). But the procedure of declaring the activity in the Manifest.xml and getting permissions for using this ad lib seems very much specific to the adlib that is being used. But, what happens if I wish to use to some other ad lib like **Millennial Media** or **Inmobi**. Is there any generoc way to find the adlib being used (like parsing the xml for a specific tag or looking into the code for a particular API call?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of going through the source code of each open-source app and looking for relevant JARs, an easier way to go about this is to use this Android app called Addons Detector. The app will analyse all the add-ons you have in each installed app. It works really well in detecting which ad network your apps are using.

Google Play [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.denper.addonsdetector&hl=en).

EDIT: 
An other way to approach this is to use a software like Charles (charlesproxy.com). This essentially analyses all the HTTP traffic on your network. So you can run the app and then monitor the HTTP packets on Charles. This way you will be able to detect the ad-networks that are being used. It might be pain-staking but it will definitely work.

Comment: Thanks Sohan. This app is capable of finding the ad libs in the apps that are installed in phone i.e. if performs an "on device" search for ad libs. But, I need to to the analysis off line. I have downloaded the apps' apks from google play store and **from these downloaded apks, I need to find the ad libs. So searching for ad libs in the installed apps does not fit my requirement**. Please help me do the same thing off line (out of the device).

Comment: An other way to approach this is to use a software like Charles (http://www.charlesproxy.com/). This essentially analyses all the HTTP traffic on your network. So you can run the app and then monitor the HTTP packets on Charles. It might be pain-staking but it will definitely work.

Comment: No problem! I'm adding an edit to the answer. Can you please accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

This paper gives a list of major ad libraries, which may be helpful in setting up your DB: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1303.0857.pdf

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: @kleopatra ArXiV links don't expire. I'm not sure how you could have a stand-alone synopsis of a list of libraries. Just Passing has already described what the link points to and its relevance. It's great that you're helping new users, but in this case I think the poster has done everything right.

Answer (score 1):

Analyze libs folder for files matching InMobi*.jar, GoogleAdMob*.jar, etc.

Comment: The problem is I am analysing 1000s of apps and **I do not know the exact name of all possible android ad libs**. Without knowing the names of all possible ad libs (with their proper versions) this string based search in the "libs" folder will not work. Please suggest some technique that is general (like looking into the src code or manifest that provides guaranteed results)

Comment: You need to build and maintain database of possible libraries (maybe for major ad networks), just names should be enough, versions could be matched as wildcard. Other way is to use some kind of heuristic, maybe look for some words in package or class names like AdActivity, AdRequest, AdView, Interstitial etc. There is no API call which is specific just to ads.

Comment: Ok, thank! I am doing exactly what you have mentioned in the previous comment. Also, **I wish to ask if I reverse engineer the code (construct call graphs/ CGFs)** can I find the presence of ad libraries more precisely?