# Detecting activities with ads in android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, bytecode, dalvik

I am working on a project to detecting ad banners in particular activities (i.e. activities which contains ad banners). There are several ad possibilities, google ads, marvel ads, amazon ads. Most of them are using some kind of ad view objects in activities. What are the possible ways I can detect them from android byte code analysis? One possible way is to look for the declaration of those ad views in the byte code. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Please read this [How can I find the ad library used by an android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544883/how-can-i-find-the-ad-library-used-by-an-android-application). 
Basically, if I were you, first, I will try to find all class names within the scanned APP, and use regular expression to search for something like +Ad* (how to find class names within an APP refer to this [Find all classes in a package in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446036/find-all-classes-in-a-package-in-android))

second, I will go through library names within an APP, try to find lib files matching InMobi*.jar, GoogleAdMob*.jar, etc.

In the end, probably will do my best to design some solution for Ad network detection.